# Maclaurin expansion of $(1+x)^{82}$ and its accuracy

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, power-series, taylor-expansion

Sorry for the title it may be a very bad one. The whole question is as following:

How many terms of the Maclaurin expansion of $(1+x)^{82}$ are needed to guarantee finding a value of $1.1^{82}$ accurate to within $10^{-6}$?

Comment: This should be pretty straightforward to solve with the Lagrange remainder.

Comment: I will appreciate and thank you if you clearly explain it in the answer please.

Comment: @Crostul I missed this, thanks and sorry for duplicate.

Comment: @Crostul I asked a question on comment there. It seems that the guy who answered the question is not online nowadays. Are my questions seen in other people's screens?